# Spring decode %99 (the percent character with two hexadecimal digits) to an invalid character on application/json post/put requests?

Tags: spring

I've got an issue with the '%99' string. I have a query string with '%2599' (which is an encoded form of %99) that I pass in a PUT request, but at the spring controller, it gets converted to an invalid character. I do encode this string using encodeURIComponent on the client side, which converts this to '%2599," but on the controller side I don't receive '%99' in the request object. Spring converts this to an unknown character, '�' and I can't decode this as well. Please help me with any input on how to resolve this issue.

I tried below in request headers:
 `{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},`

`@RequestMapping(path = {API_PREFIX}, consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})` I also tried reading requests via request. `getParameter("paramName"), @RequestBody`, Path variable, but the Spring framework automatically decodes the request body with a unknown character '�' before passing it to the controller.